# what is the correct sequence to run docker images from docker compose after docker save the images?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have saved docker images as tar files from an old laptop.

On my new laptop, I will gitclone the project which use docker-compose to build and run the images.

What is the correct step to docker load images?

is it `1. docker load images` then `2. docker-compose` ?

Comment: "use docker-compose to build and run the images" - if this is true then `docker-compose up` will be all that you will need. This will build and run the images so you shouldn't need to run `docker load`.

Comment: I found save/load only useful in air gapped environment where you cant pull from upstream. To get some official images you may need. Then push them into a private registry and use them from there.

Comment: the reason to docker save and load because the new laptop cannot access the git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're `git clone`ing the source tree, the easiest thing to do is to rebuild everything from source.  Don't bother saving or transferring the images.  Just run `docker-compose up --build` on the new system the same way you did on the old system.

If that's not an option, or if you're looking at a deployment system a little more than transferring a development environment, Compose supports [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) for pretty much exactly this case.  In the main `docker-compose.yml` file do not include any instructions on how to build an image, only how to run it without the local source tree available:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  myapp:
    image: registry.example.com/myapp:${MYAPP_VERSION:-latest}
    ports: ['3000:3000']
```

Next to this, write a second `docker-compose.override.yml` that only contains instructions on how to build the image and nothing else.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
```

I'd highly recommend setting up a Docker registry of some form.  This can be Docker Hub, something offered by your cloud provider, another third-party option, or one you [run yourself](https://docs.docker.com/registry/).

In normal use you do not need to `docker save` images at all.  Instead, build and push them to the registry.  On the remote machine, Docker will know to pull the images from the registry if they're not present.

```sh
here$ docker-compose build
here$ docker-compose push
here$ scp docker-compose.yml there:
here$ ssh there
there$ docker-compose up -d
```

Note that we do not transfer the `docker-compose.override.yml` file in this sequence, only the instructions to run the prebuilt image.

If you must use `docker save` – maybe you're in an environment where the build and deploy system are on physically isolated networks and there is no registry both could reach – then yes, you need to run `docker load` before you run `docker-compose up` on the second system.

```sh
here$ docker-compose build
here$ docker save -o images.tar registry.example.com/myapp
here$ gzip images.tar
here$ scp docker-compose.yml images.tar.gz there:
here$ ssh there
there$ gunzip images.tar.gz
there$ docker load -i images.tar
there$ docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: the reason to docker save and load because the new laptop cannot access the git repo.